# SAS How to sum a variable in duplicate records

Tags: sas, duplicates

Noob SAS user here.
I have a hospital data set with patientID and a variable that counts the days between admission and discharge.

Those patients who had more than one hospital admission show up with the same patientID and with a record of how many days they were in hospital each time.

I want to sum the total days in hospital per patient, and then only have one patientID record with the sum of all hospital days across all stays. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Comment: Have you tried `Proc MEANS` with class or by ID ? or `Proc SQL` with group by ID ?  If you have trouble with something you coded add some sample data and the code you wrote.

Comment: Please provide directly reproducible sample data and show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `select distinct` the `sum` of `days_in_hospital` and `group by patientID`  This will get what you want:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct
patientID,
sum(days_in_hospital) as sum_of_days
from have
group by patientID;
quit;
```

Comment: You don't need the `distinct` keyword since the query has a `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use proc summary.

```
proc summary data= hospital_data nway;
     class patientID;
     var days;
     output out=summarized_data (drop = _type_ _freq_) sum=;
run;
```

This creates a new dataset called summarized_data which has the summed days for each patientID. (The nway option removes the overall summary row, and the drop statement removes extra default summary columns you don't need.)